# Google Sheets time calculations; Summary doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, time, calculation

I create a spreadsheet for a rehearsal plan. I would like to calculate the hours I put in after 6 pm and get a summary of the hours at line E95. For some reason, my summary calculation doesn't work. Maybe one of you can help me out. Thanks a lot in advance!
Here's the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NSBx87sWScwe2Vtp9FOcH3BupvPJ_jzISUeAk6gSBOM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(TIMEVALUE(E4:E93)), "[hh]:mm"))
```

[image]

Comment: If I delete some of the values in column E the function doesn't work anymore. Any idea why? It's in the file here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NSBx87sWScwe2Vtp9FOcH3BupvPJ_jzISUeAk6gSBOM/edit#gid=1438598992

Comment: @Mel you can do: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(TIMEVALUE(E4:E93*1)), "[hh]:mm"))`